# Regular expression to search string from a text file

Tags: python, regex

I wrote the below code to extract two values from a specific line in a text file. My text file have multiple lines of information and I am trying to find the below line

```
2022-05-03 11:15:09.395 [6489266] | (rtcp_receiver.cc:823): BwMgr Received a TMMBR with bps: 1751856
```

I am extracting the time (11:15:09) and bandwidth (1751856) from above line

```
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

time =[]
bandwidth = []
myfile = open(sys.argv[1])
for line in myfile:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.findall('TMMBR with bps:',line):
        time.append(line[12:19])
        bandwidth.append(line[-7:])

plt.plot(time,bandwidth)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('bandwidth')   
plt.title('TMMBR against time')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The problem here is that i am giving absolute index values(line[12:19]) to extract the data which doesnt work out if the line have some extra characters or have any extra spaces. What regular expression i can right to extract the values? I am new to RE

Comment: I don't see any need to use a regular expression. Split it into words with `words = line.split()` and then the time is `words[1]` and the bandwidth is `words[-1]`

Comment: And `re.findall()` can just be `if 'TMMBR with bps:' in line`

Comment: Why would there be extra characters? The log message isn't being written by a human that will be sloppy with their typing. It's coming from a program that always generates the same message.

Comment: @Barmar sometimes it does, not sure why. But i tried the code on different files and sometimes it doesnt capture the data properly. Also sometime the bandwidth will not have 7 numbers and just have 5 or 6.

Comment: *"sometimes it does"*: please provide input for which that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?:\d+:\d+:|(?<=TMMBR with bps: ))\d+
```

- `(?:\d+:\d+:|(?<=TMMBR with bps: ))` non-capturing group.

  - `\d+:` one or more digits followed by a colon `:`.
  - `\d+:` one or more digits followed by a colon `:`.
  - `|` OR
  - `(?<=TMMBR with bps: )` a position where it is preceded by the sentence `TMMBR with bps:` .
- `\d+` one or more digits.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P51oNk/1)

```py
import re

txt1 = '2022-05-03 11:15:09.395 [6489266] | (rtcp_receiver.cc:823): BwMgr Received a TMMBR with bps: 1751856'

res = re.findall(r'(?:\d+:\d+:|(?<=TMMBR with bps: ))\d+', txt1)

print(res[0]) #Output: 11:15:09

print(res[1]) #Output: 1751856
```

Comment: This works pretty well for all the different variations of the line. One of the variation was ```[MediaClient.16336, 2022-09-06T08:42:40.205; Info]: [Video.MultiStreamWorker] (rtcp_receiver.cc:839): BwMgr Received a TMMBR with bps: 4055424```

Comment: @Sachin It also matches the value from that line is there a problem here ?

Comment: Yes it does. I was just giving an example

Comment: will you be able to help me with one more regex expression?

Comment: @Sachin Sure! I will be waiting for your response to explain what you need

Comment: I want to find some important information on the SIP call log https://regex101.com/r/oYPJcP/1 , Information like , from address, To address , type of SIP msg(INVITE), content-TYPE, RX or TX(you will see on the first line) and then put everything on a table like form.

Comment: Do you mean IP`203.252.54.20` and `192.259.19.37` address or Email address `sip:fiber@service.com` and `sips:c016130e-fa4e-454a-b249-4a6f8d6cf276@sip-203-252-54-20.bjn.vc` ?..

Also the type of SIP msg(INVITE) Do you mean this one `Response msg 200/INVITE` ? 

The `RX` value is `2702 bytes` right ?

There is no `TX` value is it optional ? and what is its value if it is there ?

Comment: 1) IP address
 2) Yes the 200 INVITE
3) i dont want the bytes data. just RX. sometime the value will be TX instead of RX(it basically means received or transferred)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251102/discussion-between-sasky-and-sachin).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bit more specific with 2 capture groups:

```
(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\.\d{3}\b.*\bTMMBR with bps:\s*(\d+)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)` Capture **group 1**, match a time like format
- `\.\d{3}\b` Match a dot and 3 digits
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `\bTMMBR with bps:\s*` A word boundary, match `TMMBR with bps:` and optional whitespace chars
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1 or more digits
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/CNTThI/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YTzRQ6).

Example

```
import re

s = r"2022-05-03 11:15:09.395 [6489266] | (rtcp_receiver.cc:823): BwMgr Received a TMMBR with bps: 1751856"
pattern = r"(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\.\d{3}\b.*\bTMMBR with bps:\s*(\d+)\b"
m = re.search(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(m.groups())
```

Output

```
('11:15:09', '1751856')
```

Comment: Thank you @thefourthbird for the answer but as i mentioned on my question, sometimes the line have variations like 
```[MediaClient.16336, 2022-09-06T08:42:40.205; Info]: [Video.MultiStreamWorker] (rtcp_receiver.cc:839): BwMgr Received a TMMBR with bps: 4055424```
In that case the regex you mentioned doesnt work.

Comment: @Sachin I see, I have updated the pattern to get those matches as well. See https://ideone.com/YTzRQ6

Answer (score 0):

You can just use split:

```
BPS_SEPARATOR = "TMMBR with bps: "
for line in strings:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if BPS_SEPARATOR in line:
        time.append(line.split(" ")[1])
        bandwidth.append(line.split(BPS_SEPARATOR)[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use context manager for handling a file
- don't use `re.findall` for just checking the occurrence of a pattern in a string; it's not efficient. Use `re.search` instead for regex cases

In your case it's enough to split a line and get the needed parts:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as myfile:
    ...
    if 'TMMBR with bps:' in line:
        parts = line.split()
        time.append(parts[1][:-4])
        bandwidth.append(parts[-1])
```